# Qt issues with skimage in OSX

Tags: python, macos, qt

I'm having a hard time finding proper steps to get skimage (and it's QT components) working on OSX. I used this example for skimage:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from skimage import data
from skimage.viewer import ImageViewer

image = data.coins()
viewer = ImageViewer(image)
viewer.show()
```

Which yielded this error:

```
/Users/marcleonard/.virtualenvs/marcleonard-zP9HSj98/lib/python3.4/site-packages/skimage/viewer/__init__.py:6: UserWarning: Viewer requires Qt
  warn('Viewer requires Qt')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/marcleonard/Desktop/image-api/image-api.py", line 7, in <module>
    viewer = ImageViewer(image)
  File "/Users/marcleonard/.virtualenvs/marcleonard-zP9HSj98/lib/python3.4/site-packages/skimage/viewer/viewers/core.py", line 93, in __init__
    init_qtapp()
  File "/Users/marcleonard/.virtualenvs/marcleonard-zP9HSj98/lib/python3.4/site-packages/skimage/viewer/utils/core.py", line 28, in init_qtapp
    QApp = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
AttributeError: 'QtGui_cls' object has no attribute 'QApplication'
```

To install Qt, I used `brew install python cmake qt` (though, presumably, this is Qt5, maybe this is the issue?)

My pipenv graph looks like this:

```
scikit-image==0.13.1
  - matplotlib [required: >=1.3.1, installed: 2.0.2]
    - cycler [required: >=0.10, installed: 0.10.0]
      - six [required: Any, installed: 1.11.0]
    - numpy [required: >=1.7.1, installed: 1.13.3]
    - pyparsing [required: >=1.5.6,!=2.0.4,!=2.1.6,!=2.1.2, installed: 2.2.0]
    - python-dateutil [required: Any, installed: 2.6.1]
      - six [required: >=1.5, installed: 1.11.0]
    - pytz [required: Any, installed: 2017.2]
    - six [required: >=1.10, installed: 1.11.0]
  - networkx [required: >=1.8, installed: 2.0]
    - decorator [required: >=4.1.0, installed: 4.1.2]
  - pillow [required: >=2.1.0, installed: 4.2.1]
    - olefile [required: Any, installed: 0.44]
  - PyWavelets [required: >=0.4.0, installed: 0.5.2]
    - numpy [required: >=1.9.1, installed: 1.13.3]
  - scipy [required: >=0.17.0, installed: 0.19.1]
    - numpy [required: >=1.8.2, installed: 1.13.3]
  - six [required: >=1.7.3, installed: 1.11.0]
```

Any ideas what may be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the same issue by installing PyQt4 with pip3:

```
sudo pip3 install PyQt4
```

In PyCharm 2017.3.4 the changes did not get applied until I changed the interpreter settings:

Settings -> Project:  -> Project Interpreter -> Install (+) -> Available Packages -> PyQt4 -> Install Package

PyQt4 requires Python 3.4. PyQt5 can be used with newer versions of Python, but the structure of PyQt5 is different from its earlier counterpart. PyQt4’s `QtGui` module has been split into PyQt5’s `QtGui`, `QtPrintSupport` and `QtWidgets` modules. The `ImageViewer` relies on `QFileDialog` that was moved to another module and will not work properly with PyQt5.